# Bamboo build plans and deploy

Tags: .net, bamboo

I am new to bamboo build and deploy plan and I wanted to check what is best way to build once and promote build to any environment.

Currently I have environment specific changes on web.config and that is done using transform web.release.config, web.dev.config, web.staging.config.

I was thinking to have one build plan to build the project and generate artifacts but msbuild transform the web.config at the build time.

Can someone please advise how can i use the build artifacts and transform web.config at deploy time for specific environment.?

Answer (score 1):

Branches are generally used for parallel development of features in a project. In your case it appears you want the same build to be able to be deployed to any of a number of environments.

You could configure your build to create all of these config artifacts, and then create multiple deploy projects tied to the build that will use only the artifacts specific to that environment to perform the deployment.

The artifact to be used could be controlled by a variable in the deploy project, allowing you to clone deployment projects and change a variable to deploy to a new environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to make any transformations for the build at deploy time in Bamboo. Depending on your needs you can make these changes with SSH script on deployed environment.

The workaround for this would be using branches - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-plan-branches-289276872.html . So you still would have 1 build plan, but you can have set different branch variables - in your case "web.release.config, web.dev.config, web.staging.config.". In the end you would have different builds for each branch which could be used on different environments.